# Stop Key from doing its Default Action - TamperMonkey JavaScript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to add a snippet to the custom script I made to fix some faulting shortcuts on the system I work on.

This snippet should deactivate the default action that `R` does when pressed on the keyboard.

I'm trying this, but it has no effective action:

```
   // STOP *R* CLICKING UNDO
(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.keycode == '82' && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
            ;
        event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
})();
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Side note: `event.preventDefault() -> e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Are you sure the undo event is executed on key press and not on key up/down?

Comment: @WaisKamal even if putting keydown on eventlistener it doesn't work!

Comment: Is undo the default behavior when pressing <kbd>R</kbd>? If this is not the default behaviour (i.e. this functionality is implemented by another script) then `preventDefault()` won't prevent it from happening.

Comment: @WaisKamal the <kbd>R</kbd> have by default the action of "undo" a change that I did on the website. This action is not triggered by my own JS TamperMonkey script, otherwise by the default code of the webpage. There is a button for "undo" also, that's why I want to stop R by activating this action. I have set other shortcuts for E and T, and when I accidentally press R it makes a mess. I don't know if it helps, but the JS path to the Undo button is:`document.querySelector("#root > div.MAMvt-ISpqPVuG8JnbF3g > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > button")` I am not a DEV

Comment: As per your explanation, this is not the "default" behavior but is rather a functionality implemented by the website. `preventDefault()` only prevents default *browser* action.

Comment: @WaisKamal I understand... so how can I get to know what is the name of the action triggered by R to avoid it? can I see it on the console?

Comment: You use the debugger to check. In Chrome, go to the sources tab. On the right pane there is an expandable list named "Event Listener Breakpoints". Check the keypress checbox then trigger the event.

Comment: when I do this, it shows me a line that has millions of characters, so I could not paste it here... I'm lost.

Comment: Can you paste a link to the page in question?

Comment: Unfortunately no, sir! It's a closed environment from the business that I work for :(
But, this is exactly what the line displays, when "Event Listerner Breakpoints are active"
https://pastebin.com/ES987H5z 
Maybe this helps?
@WaisKamal

Comment: The code seems pretty obfuscated. You will need to find where the event listener is added.

Comment: @WaisKamal if you could upvote the question, at least for me to have a second opinion into it, it would be very appreciated! thank you so much for your collaboration!